# Update a MySQL table with index from another table based on value set in both tables

Tags: mysql, join, sql-update

I am not sure how to ask this question - it might be answered somewhere, but it's kind of messy ;)

There are two tables that sort flags (labels) for objects somewhere else.

Table 1: the flags in `booka_flags`
columns of interest are id(INT) and title(VARCHAR)

Table 2: the flag items in `booka_flags_items`
columns of interest are id(INT) and flag(VARCHAR)

I want to change `booka_flags_items.flag` from VARCHAR (which is available from `booka_flags.title`) to ID (which is available from `booka_flags.id`)

My "idea" of writing this query (after some research) was the following:

```
UPDATE
  booka_flags_items
SET
  booka_flags_items.flag = booka_flags.id
FROM
  booka_flags_items
INNER JOIN
  authors
ON
  booka_flags_items.flag = booka_flags.title
```

but it does not work. Also not working is this query:

```
UPDATE
  booka_flags_items
SET
  booka_flags_items.flag = (
      SELECT booka_flags.id
      FROM booka_flags
      INNER JOIN booka_flags_items
      ON booka_flags_items.flag = booka_flags.title
)
```

What would be the right way to solve a query like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you would like to update id column of booka_flags with id column of booka_flags where title matches flags. Your updated query looks incorrect as per mysql

Try:

UPDATE booka_flags_items t1 INNER JOIN booka_flags t2 On t1.flag = t2.title
SET t1.id = t2.id

Comment: thank you, this worked... the final query is "UPDATE booka_flag_items as I INNER JOIN booka_flags as F On I.flag = F.title SET I.flag = F.id"